# oembed facebook link?

Tags: php, functions, embed, oembed

I'm trying to oembed some facebook video . . . without ay chance so far . .. I'd like to avoid any plugin for this.

I went through toe [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/oembed-endpoints) but nothing to do, I'm declaring in my functions.php like below ( I also tried to follow the steps of this [article](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/embedding-wordpress-oembed/) with no luck):

```
function oembed_facebook() {

wp_oembed_add_provider( 'https://www.facebook.com/video.php', 'https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video/oembed.json', false );
wp_oembed_add_provider( 'https://www.facebook.com/*/videos/*', 'https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video/oembed.json', false );

}
 add_action( 'init', 'oembed_facebook' );
```

Then in put in my page the following:

```
https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video/oembed.json/?url=https://www.facebook.com/facebook/videos/10153231379946729/
```

But i just have the code url being display .  .no content being embeded . . .

Id anyone could let me know what I am doing wrong ?

It will be super ! Thanks a lot for your time and help !

Comment: [Since 4.7](https://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds) Facebook embed are supported out of the box in WordPress, so you shouldn't need to do anything. I just tested your example URL in a relatively fresh install without a problem.

Comment: Hmmm when I put that link in a page template it just display the url in my side - it’s not pulling the content .... does it needs to be add in a special tag or something ?

Comment: In a template? It's not going to turn into an embed automatically if it's just hardcoded into a template. Nothing will. If you're embedding the video programatically, pass the URL to [`wp_oembed_get()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_oembed_get/`).

Comment: Hi Jacob,

Thanks for this, do you have any example by any chance ? It will be super ..  .thank you

Comment: Yes it does work, The thing is i want to only embed the image for example, not all the content ( headers , likes, and text). How is that possible ?

Comment: You can only embed what Facebook provides in response to requests to its oembed service. I imagine that the other stuff you mention is part of the deal, so to speak.

Comment: I thought this was the purpose of oembed, to be able to choose which element to 'iframe' isntit ?

Comment: No. oEmbed is a standardised way to embed content via URL. It's up to the provider what to return in response to a URL as the embedded version.